# How to create a decoder with varying input shape but fixed output shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, decoder

I was playing around with autoencoders for mnist recently and this question appeared.
*"Is it possible to create a model with varying input shape but fixed output shape?"*

*Example:*

Regularly decoder input will be e.g `keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(7, 7, 1))`, you will have some `UpSampling` layers in the model to bring shape from `(7,7,1)` up to `(28, 28, 1)`.

But what if decoder Input has unspecified shape?

Imagine convolutional decoder with input layer `keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(None, None, 1))`. Input shapes for decoder maybe be different, however, decoder's output always has a fixed shape `(28, 28, 1)`. *How to build a model that will determine how to do `UpSampling` depending on input shape it received?*

editted:
Let me know if this question does not make any sense. I will delete it;)

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @TomMcLean, 1 decoder will learn how to reconstruct image given different encoded features shapes

Comment: "Is it possible" is not a programming question. Virtually anything is possible and the ultimate answer to this question is either "Yes" or "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Conv` and `MaxPool` layers can operate on variable size input. `Dense` layers need to know the size. So before them you can put a `GlobalMaxPooling` or similar layer. For example:

```
image_1 = np.random.random((1, 500, 600, 3))
image_2 = np.random.random((1, 200, 300, 3))
y = np.ones((1, 28, 28, 1))

inputs = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
l = inputs
l = Conv2D(128, 7, activation='relu', padding='same')(l)
l = MaxPooling2D(2)(l)
l = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(l)
l = Dense(14*14, activation='relu')(l)
l = Reshape((14, 14, 1))(l)
outputs= UpSampling2D((2, 2))(l)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(image_1, y)
model.fit(image_2, y)
model.summary()
```

The model will accept variable size images, and has an output of shape  `(28, 28, 1)`. Model summary:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, None, None, 128)   18944     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, None, None, 128)  0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 global_max_pooling2d (Globa  (None, 128)              0         
 lMaxPooling2D)                                                  
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 196)               25284     
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 14, 14, 1)         0         
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D  (None, 28, 28, 1)        0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
=================================================================
```